# Register heroku's API key in GIT

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a java app to heroku using git. I can't find a way to register the Heroku API key in my git environment without the Heroku CLI tool (which is built in ruby).

Is there a way to use Heroku+git without installing ruby, or register my public key within Heroku like is done in github?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Heroku's Java implementation but they don't expose a GitHub web interface for uploading your SSH keys I'm afraid so you're going to have to install Ruby and do it via their CLI. Unless you're on a Mac where you actually already have it.